# What is the equivalent of PL/SQL Records in SAP HANA and how can we use it?

Tags: plsql, hana

If I want to store an entire row of a database table into a variable just like we do using records in PL/SQL, how can I perform the similar function in SAP HANA?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that in SAP HANA. 
You can iterate over a cursor and in the loop the row variable is accessible.

example:

```
do 
begin
declare cursor mc for 
        select * from my_table;

declare my_ID INTEGER;

for mc_row as mc do        

  my_ID = mc_row.ID;

  select :my_ID from dummy;

end for;
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example code here so that it could be more understandable.